# PGFPLOTS: plot with dates on x-axis?

Tags: pgfplots, dateplot

I'm trying to create a simple plot from a csv file similar to:

```
date,anumber
01/09/2021,123
...
```

I copied a bit of code  from the web:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\sisetup{
    round-mode          = places,
    round-precision     = 2,
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                    width=15cm, height=8cm,
                    grid=major,
                    grid style={dashed,gray!30},
                    xlabel=Gaming Day,
                    ylabel=USD,
                    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},anchor=north},
                    xmode=log,
                    log ticks with fixed point,
                    xtick=data,
                    ybar, %added here
                    ]
                    \addplot[fill] table[x index={0},y index={1}, col sep=comma] {myfile.csv};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{Performance Comparison Histogram}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But I get an error: `Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '01/09/2021', which makes sense, since this isn't a number. What I want to achieve is a graph where the dates label the x-axis, and the numbers are plotted along the y-axis. Sorry if this elementary, but how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{
    pgfplots.dateplot,
}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\sisetup{
    round-mode          = places,
    round-precision     = 2,
}

\begin{filecontents}{file1.csv}
    date,anumber
    2021-10-07, 123
    2021-10-08, 345
    2021-10-09, 123
    2021-10-10, 345
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \begin{center}
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                    date coordinates in=x,
                    table/col sep=comma,
                    xtick=data,
                    xticklabel style={
                        rotate=90,
                        anchor=near xticklabel,
                    },
                    xticklabel=\day.\month.\year\,
                    width=15cm, height=8cm,
                    grid=major,
                    grid style={dashed,gray!30},
                    xlabel=Gaming Day,
                    ylabel=USD,
                    ]
                    \addplot  table[x=date,y=anumber] {file1.csv};;
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{Performance Comparison Histogram}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]